# putty send null

Tags: putty, smtp

Using Putty, how can someone send a null character, ie \0

I have seen `control+@` but that doesnt seem to work.

I'm trying to do manual SMTP AUTH:

```
EHLO
AUTH PLAIN username\0\0password
```

Comment: Use %x00 - this is known as UTF8NUL.

Comment: Another possible issue:  in the examples I've seen using AUTH PLAIN, it looks like the user name and password need to be Base64 encoded.

Comment: none of the methods from wikipedia or "alt+000" or "alt+256" seem to work for me. related: http://superuser.com/questions/61742/insert-a-null-character-ascii-00-in-notepad

Comment: `control+@` is under Mac OSX only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following worked for me when using PuTTY on windows with a local serial port.

1. Under Window->Translation choose "ISO-8859-1:1998 (Latin-1, West Europe)"
2. Send your null using alt+0256

On Mac I used the 'screen' program.

1. Open the OS X terminal program, and run `screen /dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART 115200`  Use the path of your own serial device, something in `/dev/tty.*`  115200 was the baud for my specific device.
2. Send null with `^@` (Ctrl+Shift+2).  See [This SU Post](https://superuser.com/a/293270/94741)

References:

1. [Serial Console on OSX](http://etherealmind.com/serial-console-on-osx/)
2. [SU Post](https://superuser.com/a/293270/94741)

Comment: When using alt+025 it works, thanks for the trick. But if I paste "^@" into PuTTY it doesn't, the receiver SMS shows "Üi".?
Another thing the manual to my Siemens TC65 modem says the escape sequence is "\\00". It worked a few days ago but suddenly it doesn't. I can't get wise on thoses escape-sequences :-(